# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:clean'

Tags: android

I clean and build the application and trying to run but is throwing this exception.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /android studio project/Glide/app/build
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: restart android studio.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/26n7ps/exeuction_failed_for_task_cleanandroid_studio/)

Comment: @ Neet Soni: Restarting the android studio is not a solution i am getting this  exception  while running the application

Answer (score 1):

I was using Java 7. Updating it to Java 8 solved this problem for me. It seems to be a java version issue.

Answer (score 0):

killed all the `java TM processes` in the task manager and  rebuild. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do following things.

1. Open Task Manager
2. Select current user(which is you).
3. Select "AndroidInterface"
4. CLick on Disconnect button.

Then Rebuild project it will work...

Answer (score 0):

1. close Android Studio.
2. Open it Again.
3. Give the name of your project in the first edit box and then press tab to switch to the next text box and then change the default location.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle process holds file locks, so either kill any `java.exe` processes manually or be more precise and kill all Gradle daemons by issuing this command in your project root directory:

```
gradlew daemon --stop
```

This will stop all daemons of particular Gradle version.